# Return image as an element's background

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JavaScript Function that creates an image:

```
    var imageFoo = document.createElement("img");
    imageFoo.src = dataUrl;
    imageFoo.classList.add("waveform");
    imageFoo.id = "wvf";
```

Now if I add:

```
document.body.appendChild(imageFoo);
```

Returns the image to the body of the page. All working.
But What I try to do is to return this image as the background of an element. I tried the following:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mejs-time-total");
x[0].style.backgroundImage = dataUrl; //I tried with imageFoo.src too
```

And it won't load the image.

If I link it to one of the images on my disk, it will load the image:

```
x[0].style.backgroundImage = "url(https://localhost:44384/Content/images/waveform.png);
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you try `x[0].style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dataUrl + ")";`?

Comment: No, seems that this solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var imageFoo = document.createElement("img");
    imageFoo.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=1-3";
    imageFoo.classList.add("waveform");
    imageFoo.id = "wvf";

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
x[0].style.backgroundImage = "url("+imageFoo.src+")"
```

```html
<div class="data">
  sample
</div>
```